# I can't skip the google ads by using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to learn test automation and I've been trying to automate a website by using Java Selenium Webdriver but I am not able to skip google ads.

I tried to click them by using JS Executer or by the method swich.alerts();
But ads are sometimes visible but sometimes not. They also have different xpath or css everytime.

I installed Adblock and add those lines below but couldn't solve my problem.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
                        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                        options.addExtensions(new File("... /my path/..."));
```

So I'm stuck at that point. Without not passing that part, I cannot continue to automate the other parts of the website. I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8z9O.png)

Comment: [Selenium + Java: Unable to close Advertisement in webpage](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49864/selenium-java-unable-to-close-advertisement-in-webpage) sound similar and what you are trying to solve